# Jupyter lab seems not to connect to Julia REPL

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

How to make Jupyter lab work with Julia?

I work in VirtualBox VM Ubuntu 22.04 and use Miniconda and I have done the following:

1. I open a terminal window
2. I made an environment julia and installed with conda Julia 1.9.2 and this env now active
3. I install with conda jupyterlab
4. I start up Julia and works fine and do:

   1. using  Pkg
   2. Pkg.add("IJulia")
   3. Pkg.update()
   4. Pkg.build("IJulia")

Not sure what to do next. Instructions I read do not tell, or  instruct me to start up Anaconda Navigator, which I have not accessible from the command line, what I understand.

I open another terminal in parallel and make env julia active
I give the command: jupyter lab - and jupyter lab  start up.
I choose kernel Julia 1.9.2
I make simple commands like x=1+2; print(x)

But only get a star to the left.

If I choose kenrel Python 3 instead and run the same code it all works.

Somehow the Jupyter lab notebook "does not  connect" with the  Julia language.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would usually try to start Jupyter lab from Julia, rather than the other way around. I.e., do:

```
julia> using IJulia

julia> jupyterlab()
```

That should open Jupyter lab running from the miniconda that IJulia installs by default.

Comment: After entering "using IJulia" I get ERROR: LoadError: InitError: could not load library "libmbedtls.so" libmbedx509.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory. Stacktrace:....

Comment: Is it perhaps a problem that Julia was installed using Miniconda? And do I need to set the PATH for Julia somehow?

Comment: Yes that likely won't help - install Julia using `juliaup`, then try again. https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup

Comment: Should I install juliaup using miniconda?

Comment: Here is also something called conda.jl but not really sure if that is right https://juliapackages.com/p/conda

Comment: I installed using conda (in the same environment where I already had Julia and jupyterlab installed) and it all works!

Comment: Glad it worked, and somewhat surprised as usually things go wrong when everything runs through conda. The simplest thing on Ubuntu is just to follow the directions on their readme: `curl -fsSL https://install.julialang.org | sh`, then just `juliaup add release` to install the latest release which will also create the symlink so you can start Julia by just typing `julia` in the terminal.

Comment: I am curious to read the readme. Needed to install curl, and ok. But the command you give start some download (and likely installation of Julia?), that get problems "Failure writing output to destination".